# Delivery Receipt using TIdMessage

Tags: email, delphi, indy, delphi-xe3

Is there a way to ask for **delivery receipt** (`Return-Receipt-To`) using `TIdMessage`?

I have an application that sends emails via SMTP, I'm using `TIdMessage` but it seems like only read receipt is working (`ReceiptRecipient` property).

I'm aware that delivery receipt isn't supported by all email servers, but if the user already knows it works using their email client (for example, they see it works on MS Outlook) they want it to work with my SMTP email application too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient` property sets both `Disposition-Notification-To` (read receipt) and `Return-Receipt-To` (delivery receipt) email headers.

If you don't want `Disposition-Notification-To` set, then leave the `TIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient` property blank, and then use the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property to set just the `Return-Receipt-To` header.

Comment: When I use `TIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient` I only receive the read notification though..

Comment: I don't know if the syntax is correct (I looked on `IdMessage.pas`), now I tried setting `ExtraHeaders.Values['Return-Receipt-To'] := '"sender name" <email@test.com>';` and leaving `ReceiptRecipient` empty but there's still no delivery notification...

Comment: The syntax is fine. If things are not working for you, then the receiving SMTP server is simply not processing these headers the way you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was suspecting..